# XElement.Parse Processing Instruction

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I am trying to parse some html into xml. The html is pasted from MS Word and is saved to a DB as a string:

```
&lt;font face="Times New Roman" size="3"&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;p style="margin: 0in 0in 10pt 0.5in; text-indent: -0.25in; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1;"&gt;&lt;font size="3"&gt;&lt;font face="Calibri"&gt;&lt;?xml:namespace prefix =" "o"" /&gt;&lt;o:p&gt;&lt;span style=";"&gt;Some text&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/o:p&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;font face="Times New Roman" size="3"&gt;&lt;/font&gt;
```

I am trying to decode the string with and create a valid XML XElement:

```
  String html = String.Format("<html>{0}</html>", 
                              HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(
                                  comment.Value
                                  .Replace("<br>", "<br/>")
                                  .Replace((char)0x3A, 'x')));

  XElement parsedComment = XElement.Parse(html);
```

With gives me the following String:

```
<html>
    <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">  </font>
    <p style="marginx 0in 0in 10pt 0.5in; text-indentx -0.25in; mso-listx l0 level1 lfo1;">
        <font size="3">
            <font face="Calibri">
            <?xmlxnamespace prefix =" "o"" />           
                <oxp>
                    <span style=";">Some text</span>
                </oxp>
            </font>
        </font>
    </p>
    <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">  </font>
</html>
```

As you can see MS Word creates a non-compilent Processing Instruction:

```
<?xmlxnamespace prefix =" "o"" />
```

It should be

```
<?xmlxnamespace prefix =" "o"" ?>
```

And I get this error:

```
"Unexpected end of file while parsing PI has occurred. Line 1, position 338."
```

How can I easily remove the processing from the input string or is my approach wrong?